# Django context isn't passing information to template

Tags: python, django, django-views

I try to pass information to an html template from a view function. Every time I try to call the variable from the html template it doesn't show anything.

Here is my *configure_peplink.html*:

```
{% extends "base_generic.html" %}

{% block content %}
<h1>Configure Peplink</h1>
<p>Configure a Peplink router from the web. This was designed by <em>Valorence LLC</em></p>
{% if peplink %}
    <p>Serial Number: {{ peplink.serial_number }}</p>
    <p>IP Address: {{ peplink.ip_address }}</p>
    <p>Mac Address: {{ peplink.mac_address }}</p>
    <p>Name: {{ peplink.name }}</p>
{% else %}
<p>No Data Found Off Device</p>
{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

Here is the view function *configure_peplink*:

```
def configure_peplink(request, peplink):

    selected_peplink = PeplinkDevice.objects.get(serial_number=peplink)
    print(selected_peplink.ip_address)
    print(selected_peplink.serial_number)
    print(selected_peplink.mac_address)

    context = {
        'peplink': selected_peplink
    }

    return render(request, 'configure_peplink.html', context=context)
```

Here is the url line to call the view:

```
re_path(r'^configurepeplink/(?P<peplink>.*)/$', views.configure_peplink, name='configurepeplink')
```

I've tested to make sure that the context has data in it (as seen with the print statements). Even though the context variable has data and is getting past the if statement in the html template it still doesn't display any data. I have tried clearing my cache on the browser and restarting all my services (django, celery, redis-server).

Here is a picture of the webpage:
[image: Webpage Image]

Comment: 1) I have found class based views easier to work with in Django, as you can specify context with get_context_data in the view class.  2) Also you might want to look at Django debug toolbar.  It allows you to see the details of what variables are available for pages and templates from within the 3) Also check the signature for render.  I thought context was a positional arguement

Comment: Did your print statements on the view print anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *peplink* variable (which is being used by the regex url and the view function) seems to be causing the problem. Change the name of the key or change the regex url variable for this to work. To get this to work by changing the key name in the view function do the following in the view function:

```
def configure_peplink(request, peplink):

    selected_peplink = PeplinkDevice.objects.get(serial_number=peplink)
    print(selected_peplink.ip_address)
    print(selected_peplink.serial_number)
    print(selected_peplink.mac_address)

    context = {
        'selected_peplink': selected_peplink
    }

    return render(request, 'configure_peplink.html', context=context)
```

Then change the html template to the following:

```
{% extends "base_generic.html" %}

{% block content %}
<h1>Configure Peplink</h1>
<p>Configure a Peplink router from the web. This was designed by <em>Valorence LLC</em></p>
{% if selected_peplink %}
    <p>Serial Number: {{ selected_peplink.serial_number }}</p>
    <p>IP Address: {{ selected_peplink.ip_address }}</p>
    <p>Mac Address: {{ selected_peplink.mac_address }}</p>
    <p>Name: {{ selected_peplink.name }}</p>
{% else %}
<p>No Data Found Off Device</p>
{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```